# When auto-generating code from XAML, why doesn't Visual Studio subscribe to events last to avoid NullReferenceExceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Imagine you have a WPF project with a main window like this:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="Test" TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" />
        <TextBox Name="TextBox2" />
    </StackPanel>
```

and codebehind like this:

```
        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        }
```

When you run it you get a `NullReferenceException`, because `TextBox2` does not exist at the time that `TextBox1` is initialized and its `Text` set, which raises the event. To avoid this, I can either subscribe to the event in the window's constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`, instead of in XAML, or add a check for `IsLoaded` at the top of the event handler. Both of these seem a little hacky.

Wouldn't it be better if the auto-generated code from the XAML initialized all controls but waited to subscribe to events until the end? In most cases I can't imagine you'd actually want to raise an event in the constructor anyway. Am I missing a reason why this would be a bad idea? I realize this might break existing code, but it could be an optional feature that only starts out enabled for new projects.

Comment: Because you're not really supposed to be doing that kind of stuff in code-behind. I realize your example is probably contrived, but the ability to use bindings obviates the need to assign a property of one control to another.

Comment: @JohnV Yes, consider it a contrived example. Surely there are legitimate uses of event handlers that refer to other controls.

Comment: why not check null in event handler? it is common practice even in winforms. (i remember combobox selectindexchanged has similiar issue, reproducible usign only one combobox  control with items filled in designer!).

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, that would work too, but also feels hacky to me. It seems like it wouldn't be necessary if Visual Studio made this relatively minor change.

Comment: so it is exactly opinion based, sorry. i partly agree with that. but even ide move all events registration to last lines of initializecompontment, it cannot gurareetee no null exception. since you can do anything(delete all controls for example) in previous event handlers, right?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, I suppose if you're writing ultra-robust code you would be null-checking everything anyway. The question could be opinion-based, but I thought maybe there was an obvious reason I was missing.

Comment: i though either microsoft guys are lazy to solve this low priority issue, or for performance considerations.

Comment: A few reasons come to mind:
1) WinForms did it this way, and if you look at the auto-generated code for XAML, you'll see that it does everything in the order it is declared in XAML.
2) The developer is responsible for when the component is instantiated, initialized, and the datacontext (if any) is assigned, so if they don't like the order things are happening in, they can easily change it.

Comment: @JohnV It doesn't seem to follow the XAML order since it must subscribe to the `TextChanged` event before setting the `Text`.